# Pointing MS Access to a variable path in VBA for exporting to Excel

Tags: ms-access, vba, export-to-excel, ms-access-2013

I have a project I work on frequently, the data comes in Access & I need to export to Excel. The following code always worked until my company upgraded to Windows 2010 a couple of years ago. What happens is I'll point to the subdir I want (e.g. P:\project\evaluation\output) and it will save one subdir up (e.g. P:\project\evaluation).

The code:

```vb
Sub ExporttoXL()

Dim response, today

exportdir = fncOpenFolder()

today = Format(Date, "mmddyy")

response = InputBox("What is the date for the title of the output file? (Recommend: mmddyy format)", "Output file date for name", today)

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
    "Query001", "Output-" & response & ".xls"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
    "Query002", "Output-" & response & ".xls"

End Sub
----------------
Public Function fncOpenFolder() As String

Dim fdlg As Object

Set fdlg = Application.FileDialog(4) 'msoFileDialogFolderPicker

With fdlg
   .AllowMultiSelect = False
   .Title = "Select Folder"
   If .Show = -1 Then
      fncOpenFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
   Else
      fncOpenFolder = ""
   End If

End With

Set fdlg = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *FileName* argument to `TransferSpreadsheet` is supposed to be *"the file name and path of the spreadsheet you want to import from, export to, or link to."*  But your code is giving it only the file name without the path.  The *exportdir* variable is not used after you give it a value from *fncOpenFolder()*.

Revise the code and use *exportdir* to include the path with the file name for the workbook which you want as the export target ...

```vb
Dim strFullPath As String
strFullPath = exportdir & "\Output-" & response & ".xls"
Debug.Print strFullPath '<- view this in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there
'DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
'    "Query001", "Output-" & response & ".xls"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
    "Query001", strFullPath
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you!